# Problemas deteniendo un grupo de servidor en jboss

Tags: wildfly, jboss-as-7

Tenemos una herramienta que ejecuta el comando para detener el grupo de servidor utilizando el shell de jboss-cli.sh:

> jboss-cli.sh --connect --command='/server-group=SG_BD:stop-servers'

Es la primera vez que no funciona, lo cual tuvimos que bajarlo desde la consola web del jboss.

Lo único que pude encontrar en el log del server.log fue que sí le llegó la instrucción, solo que simplemente no lo ejecutó:

> 2021-09-27 00:01:12,765 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 245) WFLYSRV0236: Suspending server with no timeout.

Lo cual el usuario ejecutó varias veces la bajada y envió varias veces este mensaje:

> {
> "outcome" => "cancelled",
> "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0271: Operation cancelled",
> "rolled-back" => true }

Hicimos unas pruebas más tardes y sí funcionó y varias veces después con éxito, lo que se puede apreciar en el server.log:

> 2021-09-27 06:18:41,171 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 105) WFLYSRV0236: Suspending server with no timeout.
> 2021-09-27 06:18:41,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (main)
> WFLYSRV0240: ProcessController has signalled to shut down; shutting
> down 2021-09-27 06:18:41,290 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment]
> (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0011: Unbound JCA AdminObject

Qué pudo haber ocasionado que no se haya podido realizar la bajada? He buscado, pero al parecer nadie le ha pasado ya que al parecer la mayoría utilizan la consola web del jboss por lo que no perciben este error del shell, de igual forma es la primera vez que ocurre después de 3 años de uso.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier aporte, gracias.